How does googletest guarantee that we pay for the set-up only once, without making tests depend on each other?
In GoogleTest documentation, here: https://google.github.io/googletest/primer.html it is written:


Tests should be fast. With GoogleTest, you can reuse shared resources across tests and pay for the set-up/tear-down only once, without making tests depend on each other.


Specifically it is written that "pay for the set-up only once".
In that case, wouldn't it be possible that for example:

Set-up created some object x.
Test1 corrupted x.
Then Test2 is affected by Test1?

I'm clearly missing something... what is it?

The test that is dependent on the setup of object x should not be modifying object x.  If it needs to modify object x, the test should make its own object x and that should not be part of the setup.  Imagine that all the tests are being run in parallel.

What do you think you’re missing? You’re basically asking if you can break code by deliberately breaking shared state. Sure, you could do that.

Read another section of documentation to get good explanation


Test should be fast... yes. But more importantly the order in which tests run should not affect the results.  Making unit tests (which google test is for) fast is usually about NOT having a big setup in the first place. But to work a lot with mocks/stubs/fakes you can inject into the code under test. In general I don't even use the setup/teardown at all (which also allows tests to run in parallel).  So what are you currently doing in setup? If you are reading files/opening databases/connecting to servers you are not unit testing but doing integration tests.


You can reuse shared resources across tests only if tests do not modify these shared resources.
As Marek R pointed out in here is comment. This limitation is mentioned later in GoogleTest's documentation:
"GoogleTest creates a new test fixture object for each test in order to make tests independent and easier to debug. However, sometimes tests use resources that are expensive to set up, making the one-copy-per-test model prohibitively expensive.
If the tests don’t change the resource, there’s no harm in their sharing a single resource copy. So, in addition to per-test set-up/tear-down, GoogleTest also supports per-test-suite set-up/tear-down. "
From here: https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#sharing-resources-between-tests-in-the-same-test-suite
